# How should I solve the following bvp?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

**Q:** How should I solve the following exercise:

*Give the particular solution to the following boundary value problem:*

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = ({\ln{e^x}})^{1/y}, \, \hspace{3mm} y(1) = -1$$

I know that $\ln(e^x) = x$ so that the problem comes down to solving

$$y = x^{1/y}dx, \hspace{5mm} y(1) = -1$$

But I can't get much further..

Comment: you have this $\ln (e^x)^{1/y}=\frac xy$  or is it $(\ln (e^x))^{1/y}=x^{1/y}$ ???

Comment: President then it equals $\frac xy$ and $y'y=x$

Comment: I dont understand what you mean

Comment: I mean then $\ln (e^x)^{1/y}=\frac xy$

Comment: $(\ln(e^x))^{1/y}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$dy/dx = ln(e^x)^{1/y}, y(1) = -1$$
$$dy/dx = ln(e^x)^{1/y}$$

$$(e^x)^{1/y}=e^{x/y}$$
$$dy/dx = ln(e^{x/y})=\frac{x}{y}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x}{y}$$
$$\frac{ y^2}{ 2}=\frac{x^2}{2}+C$$

Given $y(1)=-1$

$$\frac{ (-1)^2}{ 2}=\frac{1^2}{2}+C$$
$$C=0$$

$$\frac{ y^2}{ 2}=\frac{x^2}{2}$$
$$y^2-x^2=0$$

Comment: Thanks! But I meant $(\ln(e^x))^{1/y}$ sorry!

Comment: But in the comments, you mentioned it is $\ln (e^x)^{1/y}$

Comment: Sorry I was mistaken!

Comment: @Mr.President Are you sure ? Because it's really hard to integrate otherwise..

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this ?
$$y'=\frac 1y \ln e^x $$
then

$$ \frac 12 (y^2)'=x$$
Integrate simply